# How to read the amount of entries the lua in C code

Tags: c, lua

How can I do a count of the amount of settings that exist in my file lua

My file is as follows:

```
name =
{
      Activename = true; // setting 1
}
name1 =
{
     Activename1 = true; // setting 2
}
name2 =
{
     Activename2 = true; // setting 3
}
```

My lua code that I am trying to read the amount is below:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "name");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "Activename");
varenable = lua_toboolean(L, -1);

lua_getglobal(L, "name1");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "Activename1");
varenable = lua_toboolean(L, -1);

lua_getglobal(L, "name2");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "Activename2");
varenable = lua_toboolean(L, -1);
```

I want to create a message like this:

`printf ("There are 3 settings in Userconf.lua file"/n);`

Now that comes the question how do I make it to the lua, because I need a variable that the value of the amount of settings, e.g.:

`printf("there are %d settings in Userconf.lua file\n", Amount_to_settings);`

Comment: What does `i++` have to do with anything else in your post? If you initialized `i` to 0, incremented, then printed it, why would you expect it to have any value other than `1`? How does that line correlate with your printing of booleans from a Lua script? o.O

Comment: I think I explained wrong, read it again I edited the post.

Comment: Look at how many globals are in the file. Better yet, put them in an array an iterate that. Or iterate through the "name1" to "nameN" and count (you'll need to fix your naming structure). So on and so forth. You can't write a program by having stackoverflow to produce each line for you. Read the Lua API docs, or read Programming in Lua which covers idiomatic usage of the language and C API.